# HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Authorization Required:Username/Password Authentication Failed

Tags: unix

Iam getting the error: HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Authorization Required:Username/Password Authentication Failed
 when I trying to wget https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/8u221-b11/230deb18db3e4014bb8e3e8324f81b43/jdk-8u221-linux-x64.tar.gz.

I have oracle account and also accepted license also but getting the same error

Comment: What arguments are you giving to wget?

Comment: I am giving wget https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/8u221-b11/230deb18db3e4014bb8e3e8324f81b43/jdk-8u221-linux-x64.tar.gz

Answer (score 2):

That site requires a username/password login, but `wget` doesn't prompt for username and password automatically, so you need to pass your username and password to `wget` one way or another (check the `wget` man page for details).

Try something like this:

```
wget --user=YourOracleDotComUserName --ask-password https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/8u221-b11/230deb18db3e4014bb8e3e8324f81b43/jdk-8u221-linux-x64.tar.gz
```